# How to prefix http to multiple columns' url input from users in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, link-to

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670749/rails-method-for-standardizing-url-input-from-users) has answered the question for a single column but how do you do it for multiple columns? I've got three columns (website, fb, twitter) that I want to prefix with http in case users don't input them in the form.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
before_save :sanitize_links

private

def sanitize_links
  website = self.website
  facebook = self.facebook
  twitter = self.twitter
  links = [website, facebook, twitter]
  links.each do |link|
    unless link.include?("http://") || link.include?("https://")
      link = "http://" + link
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Update**

I've tried the suggestion by KL-7 but unfortunately hit a little snag. How do I use the output of the array with `before_save`? I've tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
before_save :sanitize_links

private

def sanitize_links
  links = ["website", "facebook", "twitter"]
  links.map! { |link| self.link =~ %r{\Ahttps?://} ? self.link : "http://" + self.link }
end
```

---

**Update 2**

I gave up. I'll just repeat it three times:

```
before_save :sanitize_links

private

def sanitize_links # prefix user-submitted links with http:// if missing
  self.website =~ %r{\Ahttps?://} ? self.website : self.website = "http://" + self.website
  self.facebook =~ %r{\Ahttps?://} ? self.facebook : self.facebook = "http://" + self.facebook
  self.twitter =~ %r{\Ahttps?://} ? self.twitter : self.twitter = "http://" + self.twitter
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
link = "http://" + link
```

in your code assigns a new value to the `link` variable withing the block, but doesn't change the corresponding element of the list.

To alter elements of the list in-place you can use [`Array#map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21):

```
links.map! do |link|
  link.include?("http://") || link.include?("https://") ? link : "http://" + link
end
```

Another thing I'm a bit worried about is that `include?` will return true even if the given substring (e.g., `'http://'` occurs somewhere in the middle of your string and not necessarily at the beginning. I'd rather use a regexp for that task:

```
links.map! { |link| link =~ %r{\Ahttps?://} ? link : "http://" + link }
```

**Update**

If `link` is an attribute of your model, then you should at least store it as an attribute and not as a local `links` variable:

```
self.links = links.map { |link| link =~ %r{\Ahttps?://} ? link : "http://" + link }
```

Comment: I tried this in the rails console:
`links = [shop.website, shop.facebook, shop.twitter]`
`links.map! { |link| link =~ %r{\Ahttps?://} ? link : "http://" + link }` and it works but I can't make it work in rails app. Any help?

Comment: I'm guessing it just change the values in the array but doesn't translate it back in the output. How do I this?

Comment: How do you mean "doesn't translate it back in the output"? It changes elements of the `links` list by prepending `'http://'` where necessary. Then you can use this array however you want.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually my fault. I'm still trying to figure out how to use the array output with `before_save`.

Comment: Well, I think that's a different question.

Comment: I updated the answer, though, it's still not clear what is `links` in your case, why do you initialize it in `before_save` filter, and how exactly you want "to use the array output with `before_save`". If my update doesn't help, you better accept my answer to this question (as we solved your problem) and open a new question regarding `before_save` with a good description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Um, I thought I've already stated this in my question above: "I've got 3 db columns (website, fb, twitter) that I want to prefix with http in case users don't input them in the form." That's why I'm using `before_save`.

Comment: Ok, in your code sample you gathered all attributes into `link` array and with my help you prefixed them all with `http://`. All you need now is to store resulting values back in the corresponding attributes. Can't you handle that yourself?